# Rails query related to polymorphic association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm trying to find a query through which I can pull the records from the database... Below is the example

```
class Apple < AR::Base
  has_many :bananas
  has_many :events, as: :eventable
end

class Banana < AR::Base
  belongs_to :apple
  has_many :events, as: :eventable
end

class Event < AR::Base
  belongs_to :eventable, polymorphic: true
end
```

Can I write any single query, where I can pull all the events of a specific apple and all the events of the bananas related to that specific apple.

Comment: so have you  an `id` of apple as an argument?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to combine the apple events and the apple's bananas' events into one collection. The simple approach, if an array suffices, is to call:

```
def events_for apple
  apple.events + apple.bananas.map(&:events).flatten
end
```

If you want the collection to be an ActiveRecord Relation, you could take the following (arel union based) approach:

```
def events_for apple
  apple_events = apple.events
  banana_ids = apple.bananas.pluck(:id)

  banana_events = Event.where(eventable_type: 'Banana', eventable_id: banana_ids ) 

  all_events = Event.from("
        (
            (
              #{apple_events.to_sql}
            ) union (
              #{banana_events.to_sql}
            ) 
        ) #{Event.table_name}
    ").distinct 
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks Anand.... I really appreciate your help. The above code worked like a charm......

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
a = Apple.first

Event.where("eventable_type = 'Apple' AND eventable_id = ?", a.id).or("eventable_type = 'Banana' AND eventable_id IN (#{a.banana_ids.to_sql})")
```

First `where` gives you all the events for the apple, second `or` gives you all the events for `a`'s bananas